# Class#isAssignableFrom with Object and double

Tags: java, reflection

I'm looking at [java.lang.Class#isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) from [Java Reflection in Action](http://www.manning.com/forman/).

Why does `Object.class.isAssignableFrom(double.class):` print to `false`, but `f` prints out to `100.0`?

```
public class IsAssignableFrom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 100;
        Object o = null;

        System.out.println("Object.class.isAssignableFrom(double.class): " + 
            Object.class.isAssignableFrom(double.class));

        Object f = d;   
        System.out.println("f: " + f);
    }
}
```

Let's run the test.

```
>javac IsAssignableFrom.java && java -cp . IsAssignableFrom
f: 100.0
Object.class.IsAssignableFrom(d): false
```

Comment: Being able to use `Object f = d;` doesn't mean that `Object` is supertype of `double` (which result of `isAssignableFrom` confirms), it just means that autoboxing will add code necessary to convert `double` to `Double` for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double` is a primitive type. There is no common supertype for primitive types. In other words, `Object.class` does not represent a superclass of `double.class`.

Boxing conversion can be applied to a value of type `double`  and convert it to a value of type `Double` which is a subtype of `Object`. That's why `d` is assignable to `f`.